# Why does Python's urlparse.parse_qs() split arguments on semicolon

Tags: python, http, get, query-string

I'm writing a test script in Python to check the output of my PHP application and I've got a problem with Python's `urlparse.parse_qs()` function. GET string delimiter (AFAIK) is an ampersand. The function (as I understand) is supposed to split a GET string into Python dictionary, so that the output for `count=2&offset=5&userID=1` should be:

```
{'count': ['2'], 'userID': ['1'], 'offset': ['5']}
```

And it is. But when I try to pass CSV in GET (separated with semicolons) such as `ids=5;15;3`, I get the following:

```
[('3', ''), ('15', ''), ('ids', '5')]
```

I think the valid output should look like this:

```
{'ids': ['5;15;3']}
```

What am I doing wrong? The line looks like this:

```
args = urlparse.parse_qs(sys.argv[2], keep_blank_values=True)
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

[';' is equivalent to '&'](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Query_string#Structure)

[W3C recommends that all web servers support semicolon separators in the place of ampersand separators.](http://www.w3.org/TR/1999/REC-html401-19991224/appendix/notes.html#h-B.2.2)

So use ',' instead.

Comment: This advice is outdated and should no longer be followed. https://stackoverflow.com/a/40768572/40013