# How to access multiple key-value in URI

Tags: ruby, web-services, api

I ran into scenario where I m taking multiple input of same field type to render a form.

To give some context:

```
GET post_ad_form/?tree_field=brand;brand=bmw&tree_field=country;country=India
```

I need to return the model for brand `"bmw"` and the cities for country `"India"` respectively.

The structure is based on "[How to design REST URI for multiple Key-Value params of HTTP GET](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13788830/how-to-design-rest-uri-for-multiple-key-value-params-of-http-get)"

How can I access `params['tree_field']`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to get query string from passed url in ruby on rails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7316656/how-to-get-query-string-from-passed-url-in-ruby-on-rails)

Comment: What is your desired output? Accessing `tree_field` is easy. What do you want after you access it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can combine [`URI#parse`](https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/uri/rdoc/URI.html#method-c-parse) and [`CGI#parse`](https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/cgi/rdoc/CGI.html#method-c-parse) to fetch params:

```
require 'cgi'
require 'uri'
url = 'post_ad_form/?tree_field=brand;brand=bmw&tree_field=country;country=India'
queries = CGI.parse(URI.parse(url).query)
#=> {"tree_field"=>["brand", "country"], "brand"=>["bmw"], "country"=>["India"]}
queries['tree_field'] #=> ["brand", "country"]
```

However, if you just have the params in a String then you can just use `CGI#parse`:

```
params = 'tree_field=brand;brand=bmw&tree_field=country;country=India'
CGI.parse(params)
#=> {"tree_field"=>["brand", "country"], "brand"=>["bmw"], "country"=>["India"]}
```

Comment: Thanks @surya. I m using sinatra gem. Well this works fine but to the project i m working i m not ment to use `CGI`.

Comment: fyi: cgi and uri are standard libraries in Ruby.

Comment: thanks, that I know. I m not allowed to use cgi gem is what i mean.

Comment: If you can't use the CGI gem then why select this as the answer?

Answer (score -1):

Your question isn't clear, but maybe this will help:

```
require 'uri'

uri = URI.parse('http://somehost.com/post_ad_form/?tree_field=brand;brand=bmw&tree_field=country;country=India')
query = URI.decode_www_form(uri.query).map{ |a| a.last[/;(.+)$/, 1].split('=') }.to_h # => {"brand"=>"bmw", "country"=>"India"}
```

which breaks down to:

```
query = URI.decode_www_form(uri.query)       # => [["tree_field", "brand;brand=bmw"], ["tree_field", "country;country=India"]]
  .map{ |a| a.last[/;(.+)$/, 1].split('=') } # => [["brand", "bmw"], ["country", "India"]]
  .to_h                                      # => {"brand"=>"bmw", "country"=>"India"}
```