# SoapUI semicolon paramter in REST request

Tags: rest, soapui

I have a login request of the form:

https://server-name/app/login.do;jsessionid=ZzrTY2hTV4FWj8NQwWnQngwvP10LQY4LK1Q7Gtm1rLpr9nqSbwpX!276696183

How do I pass a semicolon URL parameter in SoapUI?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [URL: semicolon instead of question mark](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18830192/url-semicolon-instead-of-question-mark)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per official [documentation](https://www.soapui.org/rest-testing/understanding-rest-parameters.html#1-6-MATRIX-Parameters):
You would define the parameter, `jsessionid` in your case, as a "matrix" parameter.