# Using lxml to Validate HTML

Tags: html, validation, lxml, lxml.html

I am trying to use lxml to validate a piece of HTML but it complains that the fragment is invalid even though it should be valid:

```
img = """<img src="http://api.com/?data=ey&ip=1&img=1" height="1" width="1">"""
parser = lxml.etree.HTMLParser(recover=False)
lxml.etree.parse(StringIO(img), parser)
```

raises:

```
XMLSyntaxError: htmlParseEntityRef: expecting ';', line 1, column 37
```

Changing the `&` separating the parts of the query string to `;` seems to fix the issue but that should not be required. Using semicolons is a [recommendation of the W3C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3481664/semicolon-as-url-query-separator).

Is there something I can do to get lxml to see this fragment as valid?

Answer (score 0):

I can’t test it with lxml, but I guess that you have to escape the ampersands as `&amp;`:

```html
<img src="http://api.com/?data=ey&amp;ip=1&amp;img=1" height="1" width="1">
```

Comment: I actually think what lxml _requires_ per the W3C _recommendation_ is `<img src="http://api.com/?data=ey;ip=1;img=1" height="1" width="1">`.

Comment: @AlexRothberg: Why should this be the case? There is no W3C Recommendation that requires `;` in URIs. You are free to build your URIs according to [the URI standard](http://tools.ietf.org/html/std66). In fact, by default HTML GET forms use the `&` for separating name-value pairs in the query component. Your example URI is fine; you just have to escape `&` if used in HTML attributes like `href`.

Comment: The specific recommendation Alex mentions is here: https://www.w3.org/TR/html4/appendix/notes.html#h-B.2.2